# Nfc Forum Type 4 Tag on Android

Tags: android, nfc

In the Type 4 tag spec, it identifies how to access Ndef records on the tag, and Android implements this functionality. The NDEF TLV block tells the Reader how to access the Ndef application. But the spec also specifies a proprietary File control TLV, to tell the reader how to access proprietary files on the tag (useful in many ways, like for security protocols).

My question, is there a way to access these proprietary files via Android when I connect my tag as a Ndef tag? Or do I have to connect the tag as a Nfc-A tag and write my own code to access the proprietary files AND the Ndef message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Type 4 tags, you'll have to use the IsoDep technology to talk to the tag (as Type 4 tags are based on ISO14443-4). Using  ISO7816-4 commands with IsoDep.transceive(), you should be able to read the files on the tag.

Comment: That's what I figured. For my project I was hoping there was some way I was missing that would enable me to use Ndef to do this. It would have made some development issues a LOT easier.